# Advice Needed -- Converting to IFRAME google apps Script

Tags: html, upload

I am stuck on converting my web app to IFRAME.  I have stripped the code back as much as i can and the script itself works to a point.

The issue i am having is when it was running in NATIVE, it would return some html once complete, now it gets to that point and just sits there although it has done everything correctly to that point.

I am new to this and not sure if i should post code or a link to the web app but any help would be gratefully received.

Link to web app

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXdgqwKAfbouV5CHo4wLJTpbP_d6TLIANlsU1Fvv0xk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can give code and links:)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXdgqwKAfbouV5CHo4wLJTpbP_d6TLIANlsU1Fvv0xk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: so you want that document in an iframe?

Comment: it the web app associated with that document that causing me issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an iframe with the link in `src` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXdgqwKAfbouV5CHo4wLJTpbP_d6TLIANlsU1Fvv0xk/edit#gid=703430807">
</iframe>
```

This code can you include in your website. Let me know if this is what you want.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhe9xt0d/)

Comment: not really, i want the script to return some html once its complete, showing a simple message and a button link.

currently it just stops even though the logs show it got to the point where the RETURN should have kicked in

Comment: I think its a online problem then... Google maybe blocks the scripts. Or do you have a working example?

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx1W9ajSV388cQIFMIoveyUn25f40JFa-AW2yw77YE-fBFkEnw/exec

Comment: that is the web app, you can view the code in the script editor of the first link i posted, its is combined with a google sheet